# adding google event tracking to links in posts

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to add outbound link tracking for links within my posts. But only for links that do not have an img as a child. My code is below but does not add my class to any links in my posts:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //outbound post links
    //var outbound_post_name = jQuery(this).find('h2.title').text();
    var post_link = jQuery('.post .entry').find('a');
        if( jQuery(post_link).has('img') ){
            //do not add class or tracking if the link has an img
        }
        else{
            jQuery(post_link).addClass('outbound-link');
            jQuery(post_link).click(function(){
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound Link', 'Click', outbound_post_name + 'Post Link', '', false]);
            });
        }
});
```

I also need to get the post title for my label but am unsure of how to get it set as "outbound_post_name".

If I remove the "if" statement all links get the class "outbound-link" What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this article -> http://www.optimum7.com/internet-marketing/web-development/dynamic-google-analytics-event-tracking-for-wordpress.html

Also to get the post title of the particular page. You could use the following jQuery ( Assuming you post title is wrapped in  tag ).

```
outbound_post_name = jQuery('h1').html();
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, perfect! I know I can grab my title via my h2.title tag on single post pages without problems. But when adding the post title to the vent tracking in category, archive pages I get a bit lost. I think I need to use a combination of parents() and prevAll(). I'll try it out and see what happens. Thanks again!

Comment: Here is the code that worked for me getting the post title: `code`var post_title = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('h2.title').text();`code`